# How to make the text color to be changing

Tags: android

Guys i have a textview like this

```
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/usage"
       android:layout_marginTop="220dip"
       android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
       android:typeface="serif"            
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Google"
       android:textColor="#030900"/>
```

here i need the text `Google` to change from one color to other.I mean when the text is displayed the color of text should keep on changing.

how to acheive this

Comment: please elaborate what you want ?

Comment: hey i need a text to displayed where the color of the text will be chnaging continuously

Comment: I think you should put thread or Timer after some times color is changed

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread and Create Textview object  and set **textview1.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);** CYAN is just a Example of color

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setTextColor property of TextView. Run this code in a thread to change the color of ur textview.

Random myColor = new Random();

tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255)));